# Foam like border style

Tags: css, border, styling

Is there a way to achieve this foam/paste look for a border with css?
[image: boxes with foam border]

I thought maybe using a bg image, but I need the boxes to be flexible, that means the width/height will vary depending on the length of the content inside the box.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. This is for a kids site, and no matter  how ugly you think this looks I still need to code it somehow.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a place where you can just request code. You may want to read [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that your questions are not downvoted and receive answers.

Comment: I'm not requesting code, I'm asking if this is even possible, if anyone has ever done this before. It's not like it's something really easy that anyone can do.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible but it is not very straight-forward.

- The *CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module*'s [Border Images](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images) section (and the document in general) is worth looking through.
- The article [Understanding border-image](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/), by CSS-Tricks, is informative.
- A quick look through Google also gave me the [border-image-generator](http://border-image.com/). Looks interesting.

Using pure CSS (and images) to create borders is a good idea but it has limits. For cases where you need more you can try the good old tricks of:

- Nesting (usually four) `div`s with backgrounds that are positioned and repeated in such a way as to make it appear like a border. Each nested `div` will fill in a side of the box. Because it is nested you should be able to resize the parent `div` and have the borders resize with it.
- Absolutely positioning images to fill in gaps (such as corners). When absolutely positioning an element make sure the parent element is relatively positioned.

You will have to tinker with it, to get it to work as you want, but it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go, despite being a poorly asked question with little research (you should post some code next time!) I found a solution:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images

In your example, make a perfectly square image of the foam for a border.

To make your life easier, I'd make the image width and height a multiple of 3 (W3 uses 81x81 as an example). Looking at border-image syntax:

```
 border-image:url(border.png) 27 27 27 27 round;
```

The `27 27 27 27` are the top, right, bottom, and left respective `border-image-slice`. This means on the top, the image is offset by `27`, the right is offset by `27`, etc. This works because 27px is a third of the 81x81 image, effectively getting rid of the corners (because it skips 27px in).

This is what W3 does as an example, and it works quite well. I'm not sure about the specifics, but taking a look at documentation should yield good results. In this case, if you have a 81x81 border picture and use this code, hooray! It will work. Otherwise, you're on your own!